# How to force software update on Android 2.3.4 model GT-S5830D Galaxy Ace

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, updates, samsung-galaxy-ace

According to what I've read on line, it should be Setting -> About Phone -> Software Update, but in the About Phone section I don't have that option. Just Status, Battery use, Legal information, System tutorial, Model number, Android version, Baseband version, Kernel version, and Build number.

I also tried what [lifehacker](http://lifehacker.com/5946585/force-an-android-device-to-check-for-a-system-update) recommended, which was to

> Go to Settings > Apps (or Applications) and select show All. Then find Google Services Framework and click the Clear Data button. Then click the Force Stop button.

or

> dial *#*#checkin#*#* (using the numbers on the dial pad for the letters)

But neither of these worked. Any suggestions on how to update the software, or clarification on whether or not I can at all?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: First line of that post: "Android: If you know or suspect there's an update" Do you know or suspect there is an update for a phone released like 4 years ago(?).

Comment: I'm not sure. This is the first android I've ever used and I was just given it to develop an app on. I expected I would be able to update the software somewhat.

Comment: It's very hard to believe your very first Android device is a model from 4 years ago and even then this device had no chance to receive a major upgrade. I know this site isn't stop supposed to be for recommendation but if you want to receive future major upgrades you will have to buy the top phones and even then you will probably as much receive 2 major upgrades.

Comment: It was just given to me to develop an android application on and I needed something to test it on. If it's impossible to ugrade it, that's not too much of a problem, I'll just make sure the application is compatible with gingerbread. -